# Finding rows where multiple criteria are met with many to many relationships

Tags: sql, logic

To keep things simple, assume I have a table containing clients and the products they hold like so:

```
Client_ID        Product_Held
    1            Product1
    1            Product2
    1            Product3
    2            Product1
    2            Product2
    3            Product1
    3            Product1
```

A Client can hold any combination of products, and multiples of the same product.

I want to be able to limit my query to all clients that hold only Product1 and Product2, and I have having a little difficulty figuring out the logic needed. If I do a search for all clients with Product1 and Product2, my results will include those who hold only Product1 as well as those who only hold Product2.

In the past I have resorted to just dumping my results into Excel, adding a column that combines the two fields i.e 1Product1, 1Product2, and writing a quick formula that basically says if 1Product1 exists, and 1Product2 exists, then mark as OK, and filtering out everything else, but presumably it should be fairly trivial to accomplish through my query instead.

I feel like I should have something like:

```
WHERE Client_ID exists in Client_ID + Product_Held AND Product_Held = 'Product1'
AND Client_ID exists in Client_ID + Product_Held AND Product_Held = 'Product2'
```

But having trouble with the syntax, also not sure if this is a valid method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with aggregation and `having`:

```
select client_id
from t
group by client_id
having sum(case when product_held = 'Product1' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when product_held = 'Product2' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when product_held in ('Product1', 'Product2') then 1 else 0 end) = count(*);
```

What is this doing?  The first two conditions are counting the number of times that each product appears for each client.  The `> 0` means that there is at least one of them.

The last conditions checks that the number of the two products matches all rows.  This guarantees that all products are those two products.  You could also express this as:

```
       sum(case when product_held not in ('Product1', 'Product2') then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. Although I had some trouble with my group by statement. For simplicity's sake I expressed it as one table, but it is actually several tables with joins, and the statement would only work once I included every single field in my select statement, in my group by statement as well, i.e: SELECT Field 1, Field2, Field3, GROUP BY Field1, Field2, Field3. 

I'm still learning the ropes with SQL, do GROUP BY statements always have to include every field within your select statement?

Comment: I ended up running this as sub query and then having my main query say where client_id in (query with group clause). Not sure if its the most efficient way but thats a question for another day!